# cannot verify domain for API

Tags: api, verify

I've created a TXT with the correct code on Cloudflare, where my domain is. When I come back to verify it, I select 'other', as Cloudflare is not listed and it continues to not verify.

I've tried doing a TXT with an automatic TTL and 2 minutes.

Verification failed for www.elementroc.com using the DNS TXT record method (less than a minute ago). Your verification DNS TXT record was not found. You might need to wait a few minutes before Google sees your changes to the TXT records.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to verify subdomain www, but you have added the TXT record on the apex (naked domain) instead.

```
dig txt elementroc.com +short
"ca3-40990cad916b47a8b017bb011cbb17e7"
"google-site-verification=cffal5Q1lTU3_ATSfu1GGXd1b44nmyReUZOjPWXwEfw"
```

Google attempts to find the TXT record in www.elementroc.com but there's none.

```
dig txt www.elementroc.com +short
~
```

Refer to Cloudflare KB [How do I verify a Google TXT record?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168576-How-do-I-verify-a-Google-TXT-record-).

If you want to verify your root domain, put `@` or `elementroc.com` for Name field of the record.
If you want to verify your subdomain www, put `www.elementroc.com` for Name field of the record.